# Page was loaded after validate the form ng-click function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am validating the form on triggering the save function.

I placed my control inside the form and named it **myform**.

I am using `ng-required="true"` in Name and Password textboxes.

In the `ng-click` of the **Save** button, I call the `save()` function

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControl">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="Name" placeholder="Name"
                    ng-model="Name" ng-required="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"
                    ng-required="true" name="Password" ng-model="Password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="Email"
                    ng-model="Email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <button ng-click="save()"> Save </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

In the `save()` function, I validate the form and place an alert saying if the form is valid or invalid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myControl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.save = function () {
            if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
                alert('Valid');
            } else {
                alert('Invalid');
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

Now it will trigger validation message

[image: validation message screenshot]

After entering name and password and submitting the form, the page loaded, but didn't trigger an alert message.

Comment: While debug in chrome, it shows TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that it's trying to call the form's action, which is nothing so it will reload the page. You can use [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) which will prevent the default action.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myControl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
      alert('Valid');
    } else {
      alert('Invalid');
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="save()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="Name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="Name" ng-required="true">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Password
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-required="true" name="Password" ng-model="Password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Email
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" ng-model="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
          <button type="submit"> Save </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or if you really want to keep `ng-click` you can pass the event in the save method and prevent it there

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myControl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.save = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
    if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
      alert('Valid');
    } else {
      alert('Invalid');
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="Name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="Name" ng-required="true">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Password
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-required="true" name="Password" ng-model="Password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Email
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" ng-model="Email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
          <button type="submit" ng-click="save($event)"> Save </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: In this not show validation message for each textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do

```
<form ng-submit="myForm.$valid && save()" name="myForm">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This simple snippet `ng-submit="myForm.$valid && save()"` will not call `save` if form is not valid. And this is the angular way - keep all the validation apart from business logic. `save` method should be executed only if all the form data is valid.

There are a lot of base input validation directives: `minlength, maxlength, required, pattern and etc.`. AngularJS has a great mechanism that allows you to create your own validation ([Here](https://codepen.io/SebL/post/angularjs-how-to-create-a-custom-form-input-and-custom-validations-with-a-directive) is a great article of how to implement custom validation for inputs, just in case).